# Optimizing pdf, all parameters remain same but why part of text became wiggly / wavy?

Tags: pdf, optimization

I created a document in photoshop. I converted it to large size pdf and everything looked good. When I optimize the pdf the upper part of text gets wiggly / wavy (see attached image) but the bottom part doesn't. Both the texts are exactly same font and paragraph text. Every parameter remains same. Why would the optimization work differently in different parts of the page?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What did you do to "optimize the PDF"?   Why are you "optimizing" it?  What is wrong with the PDF generated by Photoshop?  Why are you setting type in Photoshop?

Comment: Thanks! I opened it in adobe pdf  -> save as optimize pdf -> audit space usage. It tells me that 90% of the 40mb file is 'piece information'. So I tick on all the option under 'discard user data' which reduces the file size to 300kb.
The only confusing part is why would a part of text get distorted and not the other part when they are essentially the same.

I used PS because the rest of document contains images, gradient, other layers which is easier to manage in PS than in text editor.

Comment: It looks like part of it has been rasterised. You could probably test that in the final pdf by trying to select individual letters or words. The rasterised text may now just be 'a picture' & unselectable. You'd have to trace your steps back to see at what point that happened.